# Polymer Vulcanize not concatenating

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to build a small set of components using the polymer/vulcanize tool.
When I execute the commands to build out my components I am seeing that only the first component listed is built into the output.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?  I'm not a huge fan of filing bugs when there's a possibility of user error.

vulcanize version 0.3.0

commands I've tried

```
vulcanize fn-*/*.html -o output.html
vulcanize -o bad.html fn-cube/fn-cube.html fn-loader/fn-loader.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vulcanize tool will recursively read and concat your html imports from only one input html file.

So your vulcanize command should be something like:

```
vulcanize -o build.html index.html
```

If you want to build multiple pages, you could do something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.html' -exec vulcanize -o {}-build.html {} \;
```

Comment: Ahh ok! I was trying to use it like the majority of other tools. This works great for me now